# How to save ice:panelpopup renedered after refreshing page in icefaces?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces

In http://www.icefaces.org/main/downloads/os-downloads.iface after log-in when clicking any download link a modal panelpopup will open ,and if the whole of page is refreshed the modal popup still opened,how that?!

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use a rendered variable in the backing bean and set it to true.

Like this:

JSF File (Bean1.jsf):
...
...

...
...

Bean File (Bean1.java):

import ..
..
public class Bean1 {
    ...
    ...
    private boolean isrendered = false;
    public void setIsrendered(boolean b) {
        this.isrendered = b;
    }
    public boolean getIsrendered() {
        return this.isrendered;
    }
    ...
    ...
}

Best of Luck!